# heroku cannot install zbar

Tags: python, django, heroku, zbar

I have a Django application which uses zbar for barcode recognition.
It works fine on my developer machine but when i tried to deploy it to Heroku my commit was rejected with the following message:

```
 Installing collected packages: zbar
         Running setup.py install for zbar
           building 'zbar' extension
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/zbarmodule.o
           In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:
           zbarmodule.h:26:18: error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
           In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:
           /*many "undeclared" errors*/
            !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

`pip install zbar` works fine on my computer.
And i filled requirements.txt

```
cat requirements.txt
Django==1.5.5
PIL==1.1.7
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
static==0.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
zbar==0.10
```

Can anyone help me?
PS Sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language.

Comment: I've never used heroku, but are you using a virtualenv? You probably don't have permission, rightfully so, to compile things for the global site-packages. EDIT: Do you have `build-essential` installed?

Comment: @Enrico Yes, i using virtualenv. "Do you have build-essential installed" on my developer machine ?

Answer (score 3):

Check this way:

1. Create heroku app
2. Create next files

   - app.py
     `from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode`
   - Procfile
     `main: python app.py`
   - requirements.txt
     `pyzbar==0.1.8`
   - Aptfile
     `libzbar-dev`
3. And add next buildpacks:

   - `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git`
   - `heroku/python`
4. Push files and run app on heroku

source: https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/23#issuecomment-615893637

Answer (score 2):

the zbar python package is just a wrapper.

You need to use heroku buildpacks.
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/generalui/heroku-buildpack-zbar
this buildpack will install zbar on build

alternatively, you can also use this:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

and then include file called `Aptfile` in the root of your project

`libzbar-dev`

it will install `libzbar-dev` using `apt-get` so when `pip install zbar` runs, zbar will exist.

edit: include apt-get method