# ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, apt-get, zbar

I am trying to make a online bar code reader using Django framework and deploying it on Heroku.
But when I load the the page it is showing this error:

```
ImportError at /
Unable to find zbar shared library
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://libportal.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
Unable to find zbar shared library
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages

/pyzbar/zbar_library.py in load, line 65
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 31 May 2018 11:02:16 +0000
```

I searched on it and found one appropriate solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644358/heroku-cannot-install-zbar)
But in my case `pyzbar` is successfully installed using pip and then after I installed `libzbar-dev` by adding it into `Aptfile` file after seeing above solution.

---

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Can you post the location where has the `pyzbar` is installed?

Comment: I installed it by adding it into requirements.txt file so it's located here "./.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
"

Comment: But django is searching in path '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages', check if it is correct.

Comment: I checked this path on heroku server,  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages' and found this ~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages $ cd pyzbar
~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyzbar $ ls
__init__.py  locations.py  __pycache__  pyzbar_error.py  pyzbar.py  scripts  tests  wrapper.py  zbar_library.py
~/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyzbar $